# User Preferences File Not Compatible Between Win and Linux

Tags: customization, windows, linux

I'm using both Windows and Linux and I was hoping to be able to sync the userpref.blend between these operating systems but it seems it doesn't work.
I've tried with both Blender Sync and by manually moving the files without success.
Am I missing something? The .blend files should be platform agnostic, right?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Windows 10 v1903 and Blender 2.8

Best regards,
Anton

Comment: Ok, so it looks like both startup.blend and userprefs.blend actually do work when manually copying them from Win to Linux. The keymap doesn't however, so I had to export it manually as a .py file and then import it. 
Blender Sync doesn't work at all between Win and Linux though. Would be nice to get it working so we don't have to manually do these steps!